# select table data using Xpath

Tags: html, xpath, html-agility-pack

i used to select table with class name "list". I use this xpath query to select node in Htmlagilitypack

```
//table[@class="list"]/td/a[@href]
```

but couldn't get correct output. What's wrong with my xpath code block?

This is the table that i want to grab the data from:

```
<table class="list">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td width="315">
            <b>1</b> <a href="http://www.url.html">data</a><br>
            <b>2</b> <a href="http://www.url.html">data</a><br>
            <b>3</b> <a href="http://www.url.html">data</a><br>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You missed tbody and tr: //table[@class="list"]/tbody/tr/td/a[@href] or //table[@class="list"]//td/a[@href]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I consider that you need to get `href` values of all the anchors. For that you could use 
`//table[@class='list']//td/a/@href`

Your XPath did not work because you are trying to find such a `<TD>` which is immediate child of `<TABLE>` which is not the case in the code snippet you've shown. Hence use //TD in your XPath.

Hope this helps.